# como puedo ejecutar funciones de jquery por tiempos despues de hacer click a un boton

Tags: jquery

quiero hacer que al darle click a un elemento se ejecuten las siguientes funciones

```js
$( ".add-to-car-d1" ).on("click", function() {
      //al dar click que pase esto
      $('.iconcar' ).addClass('carrAnimation');
      //despues de 1 segundo pase esto
      $('.iconcar' ).removeClass('carrAnimation');
    });
```

Comment: te genera errores ?

Comment: no no se como hacerlo xD por que si solo lo pongo asi no hace nada por que pasa al mismo tiempo

Answer (score 1):

EL uso mas sencillo para el caso es utilizando la funcion [setTimeout()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)
EL funcionamiento seria el siguiente:

```
setTimeout(funcion,tienmpo);
```

Con tu ejemplo quedaria tal que asi:

```
$(".add-to-car-d1").on("click", function () {
    //La función inicial se ejecuta al principio
    $('.iconcar').addClass('carrAnimation');
    //Espera X cantidad de milisegundso y ejectua la siguiente funcion:
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.iconcar').removeClass('carrAnimation');
    },1000); // el tiempo a que pasara antes de ejecutar el codigo
});
```

Answer (score 1):

No hace falta que definas la duración del evento en tu script puesto que puedes subscribirte a los [eventos de animación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations#Adding_the_animation_event_listeners)

### Javascript Puro (ninguna librería)

```js
var rectangulo = document.getElementById('rectángulo')
rectangulo.addEventListener('click', animar)

function animar (ev) {
  var htmlElem = ev.target
  // si la animación está en curso, entonces no hacer nada
  if (htmlElem.classList.contains('animar')) return
  // si no, comenzar animación
  htmlElem.classList.add('animar')
  // subscribirse al evento "animationend". Esto hace que cuando el elemento finalice de animarse, éste llame a la función `finalizarAnimacion`
  htmlElem.addEventListener('animationend', finalizarAnimacion)
 
  function finalizarAnimacion () {
    console.log('la animación ha finalizado')
    //limpieza, esto permite que el elemento se vuelva a animar
    htmlElem.classList.remove('animar')
    // limpieza, se cancela la subscribción al evento, ésto es únicamente para impedir fugas de memoria (y por ende algunos errores en consola)
    htmlElem.removeEventListener('animationend', finalizarAnimacion)
  }
}
```

```css
#rectángulo {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative
}

.animar {
  animation-name: mover;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-iteration-count: 2 /* ida y vuelta*/
}


@keyframes mover {
  from {
    left: 0px
  }
  to {
    left: 100px
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="rectángulo"></div>
<p> Haz click en el rectángulo </p>
```

### Con jQuery

```js
$('#rectángulo').on('click', function animar (ev) {
  var htmlElem = $(this)
  if (htmlElem.hasClass('animar')) return
  htmlElem.addClass('animar')
  htmlElem.on('animationend', finalizarAnimacion)
  
  function finalizarAnimacion () {
    console.log('la animación ha finalizado')
    htmlElem.removeClass('animar')
    htmlElem.off('animationend', finalizarAnimacion)
  }
})
```

```css
#rectángulo {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative
}

.animar {
  animation-name: mover;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-iteration-count: 2 /* ida y vuelta*/
}

@keyframes mover {
  from {
    left: 0px
  }
  to {
    left: 100px
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rectángulo"></div>
<p> Haz click en el rectángulo </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias formas de hacerlo.
Si solo quieres que espere 1 segundo, puedes hacerlo con el setTimeOut()

```
$('.iconcar' ).addClass('carrAnimation');
setTimeout(tuFuncion(){$('.iconcar' ).removeClass('carrAnimation');}, 1000);
```

Otra forma es con jQuery Animation, puedes ejecutar una función luego de la otra.
Te dejo este link https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_animate.asp